# Golang - How to extract part of an XML file as a string?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, go

My XML looks something like this:

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c>
      <d>TEXT</d>
   </c>
  </b>
</a>
```

I know how to separate this code via the xml.Unmarshal function, but is there any way to perform the Unmarshal action only to a certain depth? For example, if I wanted to get a string that says "TEXT" and pass that into another function? I tried giving  a child charset object, but it still tries to parse the rest of the XML...

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you wouldn't use xml.Unmarshal,and use the string in the unmarshalled struct?

Comment: @DeanElbaz, thanks for the quick response! I am new at using Go so I may be missing something quite obvious, but when I created a string in the unmarshalled struct, it only picked up the extra characters around the child XML objects (like line breaks), but it seemed to ignore the other objects inside XML tags.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this is what you are asking (consider your comment as well).

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    type Result struct {
        Value  string `xml:"b>c>d"`
    }
    v := Result{"none"}

    data := `
        <a>
            <b>
                <c>
                    <d>TEXT</d>             
                </c>
            </b>
        </a>
    `
    err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &v)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %v", err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Printf("Value: %v\n", v.Value)
}
```

Output:

```
Value: TEXT
```

**UPDATE**: after lanZG's comment

```
func main() {
    type InnerResult struct {
        Value string `xml:",innerxml"`
    }

    type Result struct {
        B InnerResult `xml:"b"`
    }
    v := Result{InnerResult{"none"}}

    data := `
        <a>
            <b>
                <c>
                    <d>TEXT</d>             
                </c>
            </b>
        </a>
    `
    err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &v)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %v", err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Printf("Value: %v\n", v.B.Value)
}
```

Output:

```
Value: 
                <c>
                    <d>TEXT</d>             
                </c>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! The question I asked is not that easy to understand, partly because I didn't do a great job explaining the issue. In a nutshell, is there any way we can get the output to say "Value: <c><d>TEXT</d></c>

Comment: @lanZG, I updated the answer, I am not sure but it seems new one might work for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use nested xml tags to make it easier with `xml.Unmarshal`

here is how it would work: http://play.golang.org/p/XtCX7Dh45u